# How can I write a for loop that can give an output every 10 epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow

After training my model outputs all of the epochs at one time and gives one final performance indicator. How can I get it so that it'll print an epoch with a performance indicator every 10 epochs

```py
model = baseline_model()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 50)

y_pred = model.predict(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Callback

```
import keras

class Callback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, acc_threshold):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
         if epoch % 10 == 0:
             performance_indicator()
```

Example:

```
model = baseline_model()
c = Callback(0.05)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, callbacks=[c])
y_pred = model.predict(X)
```

References:

- [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51424588/7690862)
- [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/)
- [TensorFlow documentation (with keras)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback)
- [TensorFlow guide to Keras Callbacks](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_callback)